# Connecting to HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb

I'm developing a Spring Boot application using an embedded HSQLDB for local deployment. I defined the bean as follows

```
@Bean
public DataSource ds() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("classpath:db/schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:db/data.sql")
        .build();
}
```

However, when I try to fetch all the entities from the database with JPA, I get an empty result.

I would like to execute query against the embedded database at runtime to see the actual data. What port/protocol the HSQLDB listens to, and what client I need to connect and execute query?

Comment: This is a well documented feature as part of Spring Boot. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add following properties to `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

This is because the default strategy for hibernate is to drop and re-create the the database schema for the entities it manages, which negated my database scripts.